# Javascript popup window

Tags: javascript, node.js, popup

So hello guys please i need help this is my code i am trying to display id_commande in the popup window so i tried to passs it via url but it won't open after i do so

```
extends layout

block content

  h2 #{title}
  h3 #{message}
  p Commands are 
  body
    table(style='width:200%')
      tr
        th Telephone client
        th client
        th id_adresse
        //th date commande
        th date livraison
        th total
        th etat commande

      - each re in res
        tr
            ///td=re.id_commande
            td=re.telephone_client
            td=re.nom_client
            td=re.adresse
            //td=re.date_commande
            td=re.date_livraison
            td=re.total

            if re.etat_commande==1



                td(url= "http://localhost:1337/popup?var"+re.id_commande): a(href='javascript:void(0);', name='saved', title=' options ', onclick='window.open("http://localhost:1337/popup?var"+encodeURIComponent(re.id_commande),"Ratting","width=550,height=550,0,status=0,"); po=5') saved

            else if re.etat_commande==2
                td: a(href='javascript:void(0);', name='saved', title=' options ', onclick='window.open("popup.jade","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0);') valid
            else 
                td: a(href='javascript:void(0);', name='saved', title=' options ', onclick='window.open("popup.jade","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");') archived
```

Comment: Seems you have commented out your `id_commande` as             `///td=re.id_commande` in your code??

Comment: no the re has all the info i tried to tke it from re its an object but it won't work

Comment: it's not about the re[0] i want him whenever he click on a saved the first second thrid he sends te id of that line